# Bootstrap 4 Navbar toggler wont show up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I recently added my toggler button (hamburger icon) code on my html however for some reason the hamburger wont show up and looks blank whenver I resize my screen and on smaller viewport.

Her's my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Friday Hero</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-ligh" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ADVERTISE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link login" href="#">LOGIN</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

I tried to customize the color css thinking that might be the problem but for some reason the icon still won't show up. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: share your css file also

Answer (score 2):

There is a small typo:

```
button class="navbar-toggler navbar-ligh" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation
```

should be :

```
button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
```

missing a "t" in navbar-ligh

Comment: how do i change the color to white?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-ligh" ... \>`, must be `navbar-light`

Comment: how do i change the color to white?

Comment: @TonyBeatty color of what?

Comment: @TonyBeatty you can add `bg-dark navbar-dark` classes in nav tag for dark navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by adding `navbar-default` class to your code and change to your desired color by editing the css properties of the `navbar-default` class. Add the following classes to the `button` tag.

```
<button class="navbar navbar-toggler navbar-light navbar-default" role="navigation"></button>
```

and push the remaining CSS code to your Css file.

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

Comment: Try this code to change the color...and update me after checking this code snippet...Good luck ;)